# Operations on strings. Split and replace in string

Tags: javascript, html, string

When I want to check my text type variable and display every char of it then it return numbers of value. And second problem when I give the variable to replace then it's undefined. Why is that, do you think?

```
<script>

    function checkSpace(x) {
      // alert(x.value.toString());
      for (var charS in x.value.toString()) {
          alert(charS);
      }

      return  x.value.replace(" ", "");
    }


    var wykonawca = document.getElementById("informations").artist;
    var tytul = document.getElementById("informations").title;

    var addd = document.getElementById("tabelkaa");

    var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
    var row = document.getElementById("effect");


    plus.onclick = function (e) {
      var replacedText1 = checkSpace(wykonawca);
      var replacedText2 = checkSpace(tytul);

      addd.innerHTML = "Artist: " + replacedText1 + "Title: " + replacedText2;
    }
</script>

<body>
  <div id="informationss">
    <form id="informations">
      <p>Wykonawca <input type ="text" name="artist"required> </p>
      <p> Tytul <input type ="text" name="title" required> </p>
    </form> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="-" id="minus">
    <input type="submit" value="+" id="plus"> <br/>
    <div id="effect"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id ="tabelka">
    <table id="tabelkaa" border="5"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not sure what your issue is other than charS is the index of the string, not the character

Comment: You set a bunch of variables (wykonawca, tytul, etc) before the corresponding elements exist in the DOM.  So, move your script block to a place in the document after the elements it's trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

`charS` is the index. `x.value[charS]` is the letter at the `charS` position.

Also `replace(/ /g, "")` will replace all spaces.

```js
function checkSpace(x) {
        // alert(x.value.toString());
        for (var charS in x.value) {
            alert(x.value[charS]);
        }

        return  x.value.replace(/ /g, "");
    }

    var wykonawca = document.getElementById("informations").artist;
    var tytul = document.getElementById("informations").title;
    var addd = document.getElementById("tabelkaa");
    var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
    var row = document.getElementById("effect");

    plus.onclick = function (e) {
        var replacedText1 = checkSpace(wykonawca);
        var replacedText2 = checkSpace(tytul);
        addd.innerHTML = "Artist: " + replacedText1 + " Title: " + replacedText2;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="informationss">
        <form id="informations">
            <p>Wykonawca <input type ="text" name="artist"required> </p>
            <p> Tytul <input type ="text" name="title" required> </p>
        </form> 
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="-" id="minus">
        <input type="submit" value="+" id="plus"> <br/>
        <div id="effect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id ="tabelka">
        <table id="tabelkaa" border="5">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `for..in` iterates through object keys or array indexes. If you want to iterate through values, use `for..of`

Second, if you want to remove all spaces from string, use `x.value.replace(/ /g, "")` instead of `x.value.replace(" ", "")` wich will replace only the first space.

```html
<body>
    <div id="informationss">
        <form id="informations">
            <p>Wykonawca <input type ="text" name="artist"required> </p>
            <p> Tytul <input type ="text" name="title" required> </p>
        </form> 
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="-" id="minus">
        <input type="submit" value="+" id="plus"> <br/>
        <div id="effect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id ="tabelka">
        <table id="tabelkaa" border="5">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function checkSpace(x) {
        // alert(x.value.toString());
        for (var charS of x.value.toString()) {
            alert(charS);
        }

        return  x.value.replace(/ /g, "");
    }

    var wykonawca = document.getElementById("informations").artist;
    var tytul = document.getElementById("informations").title;
    var addd = document.getElementById("tabelkaa");
    var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
    var row = document.getElementById("effect");

    plus.onclick = function (e) {
        var replacedText1 = checkSpace(wykonawca);
        var replacedText2 = checkSpace(tytul);
        addd.innerHTML = "Artist: " + replacedText1 + " Title: " + replacedText2;
    }
</script>
```